# "com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-voip"how to add this key in xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit, pushkit

We are making a VOIP app and faced an issue in VOIP push notification in ios 14.

For that we got one solution like need to enable "com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-voip" this key in "entitlements" but getting below errors

**Provisioning profile "abx" doesn't include the com.apple.developer.pushkit.unrestricted-voip entitlement.**

we tried manual and automatic certificates but both faced the same error.

So for that need to enable any module in the apple account?

anyone have a solution then please help us.

Thank you

Comment: You need to get the entitlement directly from apple.

Comment: gnasher729

Can you please guide me how to get directly from apple?